# "explaining to my boss" or "explaining my boss"

Tags: sentence-choice, verb-usage

Which is correct?

> I remember futile attempts at explaining **to** my boss how this 
>   technology works.
>
> I remember futile attempts at explaining my boss how this technology works.

Is there a better way of phrasing the above sentences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We explain something **to** someone.  The direct object of **explain** is that which is explained.

> She explained the technology to her boss.

Comment: So, something like : I remember futile attempts at explaining how the technology works to my boss.

Comment: The prepositional phrase **to my boss** can be placed before or after that which is explained.   ... explaining to my boss how....   or   .... explaining how ... to my boss.

Comment: so the first sentence is correct?

Comment: The first sentence in your question is grammatical, yes.

Answer (score 0):

> I remember futile attempts at explaining to my boss how this technology works.
>
> I remember futile attempts at explaining my boss how this technology works.

Here, you haven't mentioned whose futile attempts it was at explaining to your boss about how this technology works. On the other hand, We can **explain something to someone**. So, you shouldn't avoid **to** , For example:

> I remember my futile attempts at explaining to my boss how this technology works.

You could also write **his/her/their futile attempts** if you want to.

Comment: Missing information is not a grammatical error.  Every employee in the department might have been trying to explain to the boss how the technology works.

Comment: @TRomano If the information is missing, the sentence doesn't make sense without context. The OP hasn't provided any context for his/her example sentences. So, I'd think those sentences would be understood in the proper contex, otherwis, they sound odd to me.

Comment: Without context, I'd think we should add "his/her/their attempts" in the sentence to understand the sentence.

Comment: There is no need to add anything whatsoever to the sentence to make it understandable or grammatical.  You can make it more specific by adding information, but doing so would change the meaning.